# jQuery Post Form Data to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

I am posting data to PHP from jQuery using data from an HTML form.

Here is the jQuery line that sends the POST

```
$.post("InsertNewQuestion.php", $("Create_Question_Form").serialize());
```

Here is the PHP code

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

mysql_select_db("Quizzes",$con);

$Quiz_Name = $_POST['Question'];
echo $Quiz_Name;
$Option_1 = $_POST['Option1'];
echo $Option_1;
$Option_2 = $_POST['Option2'];
echo $Option_2;
$Option_3 = $_POST['Option3'];
echo $Option_3;
$Option_4 = $_POST['Option4'];
echo $Option_4;
$Option_5 = $_POST['Option5'];
echo $Option_5;

$rowIDList = mysql_query("SELECT rowID FROM TestQuiz");

$ColumnValues = array();

$CurrentGreatestRowID = -1;

$LCV = 1;

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($rowIDList)) {

    if ($CurrentGreatestRowID < $row1['rowID']) {
        $CurrentGreatestRowID = $row1['rowID'];
    }
    $LCV++;  
}   

$CurrentRowID = $CurrentGreatestRowID+1;        

$sql = "INSERT INTO TestQuiz (rowID,Quiz_Name,Option_1,Option_2,Option_3,Option_4,Option_5,Option_1_Votes,Option_2_Votes,Option_3_Votes,Option_4_Votes,Option_5_Votes)
VALUES(".$CurrentRowID.",'".$Question."','".$Option1."','".$Option2."','".$Option3."','".$Option4."','".$Option5."',0,0,0,0,0);";

if (mysql_query($sql,$con)) {
    echo "Inserted values";
}
else {
    echo ("Could not insert values: ". mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Here is the HTML form

```
<form id="Create_Question_Form" action="" method="POST">
Question Name: input id="Question" class="Create_Question_Text_Box" type="text" name="Question_Name"><span id="Invalid_1"></span><br>
Option 1: input id="Option1" class="Create_Question_Text_Box" type="text" name="Option_1"><span id="Invalid_2"></span><br>
Option 2: input id="Option2" class="Create_Question_Text_Box" type="text" name="Option_2"><span id="Invalid_3"></span><br>
Option 3: input id="Option3" class="Create_Question_Text_Box" type="text" name="Option_3"><span id="Invalid_4"></span><br>
Option 4: input id="Option4" class="Create_Question_Text_Box" type="text" name="Option_4"><span id="Invalid_5"></span><br>
Option 5: input id="Option5" class="Create_Question_Text_Box" type="text" name="Option_5"><span id="Invalid_6"></span><br>
input type="Submit" id="Question_Submit" value="Create Question"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: The question is that the data is not being sent to InsertNewQuestion.php. Although, InsertNewQuestion.php is still called the data is not being sent so an empty row is being created.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$("#Create_Question_Form").serialize()` ? Note the `#`

Comment: I made the change it still does not work, (only empty row is still being created).

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use an auto-increment for the `rowID`?

Comment: Does your form have valid HTML? Check the result of `("#Create_Question_Form").serialize()` before posting.

Comment: And you have an sql injection hole that would break your query if any of the fields contain a `'`.

Comment: @jrummell I outputted the result of ("#Create_Question_Form").serialize() into a span to check. When I input the letter "a" into all of the fields I get this output, Question_Name=a&Option_1=a&Option_2=a&Option_3=a&Option_4=a&Option_5=a. Is that a correct result?

Comment: @jeroen I am aware there are numerous cases where certain code would make the code not work, however, my plan is to deal with that later, for now I would like to get the framework of the system to work, which for now would be getting data into the sql table from the form.

Comment: You will not be getting much data into the table if your data can easily break your query. You should take the right approach from the start and use prepared statements.

Comment: @VedaSadhak yes, that looks correct. However, I noticed that you're referencing form values by id instead of name. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form selector should be `#Create_Question_Form`. Note the `#` indicating that this is an element ID.

```
$("#Create_Question_Form").serialize()
```

**Update**

You are accessing the `$_POST` values by ID instead of name. Try this:

```
$Option_1 = $_POST['Option_1'];
$Option_2 = $_POST['Option_2'];
// etc
```

Comment: I already fixed that error still it does not work, (only empty row is being created).

Comment: It worked. The problem was that I didnt update the Options_1, Option_2 variable names in  the line $sql = "INSERT INTO TestQuiz (rowID,Quiz_Name,Option_1,Option_2,Option_3,Option_4,Option_5,Option_1_Votes,Option_2_Votes,Option_3_Votes,Option_4_Votes,Option_5_Votes)
VALUES(".$CurrentRowID.",'".$Question."','".$Option1."','".$Option2."','".$Option3."','".$Option4."','".$Option5."',0,0,0,0,0);";  Thanks everyone for the help! Great Response time!.

Answer (score 0):

```
input type="Submit" id="Question_Submit" value="Create Question"></input>
<input type="Submit" id="Question_Submit" value="Create Question" />
```

You seem t be missing a bracket